# Does the phrase "before you go" imply anything about the context of what has occurred before?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, implication

**Scenario 1:** A kid is headed out the door to school. Mother says to them "Hey before you go, brush your teeth."

**Scenario 2:** A user is on a website and wishes to close the tab. As they go to leave, a pop-up appears saying "Hey, before you go, please tell us how we did."

**Scenario 3:** A user is shutting down their account on a website. During the shutdown process/flow, a title appears at the top with the phrase "Hey before you go..." and there's maybe a form, instructions, or additional information for them.

In scenarios 1 and 2, IMHO it's very clear that contextually, the child and the user haven't actually GONE yet. Scenario 3 is a bit more ambiguous, but IMHO, it's still clear that the user is in the process of shutting down. Barring some additional comment of "Shutdown Complete", I'd assume "Before you go..." is a prompt for the user to perform some additional, perhaps optional, or cleanup tasks literally before they go, because they're not yet gone (and in this case, *gone* would imply completely shut down/done).

I'd love any insights into the grammatical nature of this contextual is/isn't "gone" across these various phrasings.

Comment: what "insight" are you looking for? "before you go, <request/demand/instruction>" means literally that: do the thing requested/demanded/etc before you "go." The instruction doesn't have to relate to the "going" at all, although it *can*.

Comment: I don't see any special grammar, or contextual interpretation.  In 1,2, and 3 the speaker is asking for the person to complete some action before they leave.  in 1, 2 and 3 when the request is made the person hasn't left, which justifies the use of "before".  So I'm mystified as to what kind of answer you actually want here.

Comment: I can imagine 'before you go' being used to mean 'While I have the opportunity to say this' - e.g. 'Before you go, I'd like to remind you to pick up some wine on the way home tonight'

Comment: @Esther - I'm making assumptions here, and am looking for insights from experts who break this stuff down regularly. I THINK my premise is correct, but I don't know precisely how to demonstrate it well using the rules of English grammar.

Comment: @JamesK - like Esther, I see where the mystification comes from. It seems clear to me as well...but I've been challenged by a client on this and I'm looking for any kind of supporting argument (or a convincing contrary argument, that's fine too) to help me (and my client) make a decision on the language choice of "Before you go..."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Exactly. It seems simple enough in each scenario to me. You haven't gone, therefore you're not *done* as it were.

Comment: I CV'd because I can't identify the source of confusion. The meaning of the conjunction "before" is well-established, and it seems to be used in that way in each of the example sentences. The answer to the question in the title seems simply to be "no", and I can't think of what more might usefully be said.

Comment: Thank you all. You've actually been a really big help to me in this.